# How to merge two dataframes using index location and backfill or forward fill for missing rows

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = 2018-01-03  0.034
     2019-05-01  0.095
     2020-05-28  0.110
     ......
     2020-05-29  0.697

df.iloc[:,0] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,0])
df.shape()
(605, 2)

s = pd.Series(pd.date_range(str(df.iloc[:,0].min()), str(df.iloc[:,0].max()), freq='D'),
          name= None)
s = s[s.dt.dayofweek.lt(5)]
df2 = s.to_frame()
df2 = 2018-01-03
      2018-01-04
      2018-01-05
      .......
      2020-05-28
      2020-05-29
df2.shape()
(628, 1)
```

I am trying to merge the above two dataframes by using index location. Df columns are Date and rates. Shape of df is (605,2). Df2 has only one column, which is the date and has a shape of `628,1`. I want to merge df with df2 and  forward or backfill the missing rates. My expected output shape should be 628,2. Can you please suggest how it can be possible by using above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `reindex`

```
df=df.set_index(df.columns[0]).reindex(s, method = 'ffill').reset_index()
```

Comment: Also adding that you may want to try pd.concat([df,df2]) in order to merge the datasets first prior to reindexing.

Comment: @YOBEN_S thanks. But I am accessing dataframe using iloc. There is no header name as 'date'. How to set_index() using df.iloc or df2.iloc